# Need Explanation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken Usage in Java Application for Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Could someone please provide an explanation for the following code that uses UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken in a Java application?

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    userDetails, null,
    userDetails == null ?
        List.of() : userDetails.getAuthorities()
);
```

I'm trying to understand how UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is used in this code to handle authentication, particularly with regards to the userDetails parameter and the null value passed as credentials. I'm also curious about the use of List.of() and userDetails.getAuthorities() for setting the authorities. Any insights would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` Authentication implementation has two constructor options:

```java
public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

/**
     * This constructor can be safely used by any code that wishes to create a
     * UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, as the isAuthenticated()
     * will return false.
     *
     */
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(null); // null is being passed to the authorities parameter
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    /**
     * This constructor should only be used by AuthenticationManager or
     * AuthenticationProvider implementations that are satisfied with
     * producing a trusted (i.e. isAuthenticated() = true) authentication token.
     * 
     */
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
    }

    // ...
}
```

The first one is used to carry the authentication data, obtained from the request, to be authenticated by an `AuthenticationProvider` capable of performing the username-password style of authentication, no matter what your users' username are, whether they're an actual username or an email, phone number, id, etc. You can define it in a `UserDetailsService` implementation.

The second one, which gets three arguments, sets the user authentication into the Spring Security's Security Context Holder. Basically, by virtue of just adding the granted authorities list to the constructor, you're saying that the users has been successfully authenticated, even though the list is empty.

That being said, there's no need to keep the user credentials stored anywhere no more. In fact, keep the user credentials stored would be a security breach, as your `Authentication` object carries the user's password as it is, i.e., not hashed.

The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` class actually has two factory methods, that can, and in fact should, be used to explicitly build an authenticated or unauthenticated token, the `authenticated()` and `unauthenticated()`:

```java
public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    // Omitted constructors and fields for brevity

    /**
     * This factory method can be safely used by any code that wishes to create a
     * unauthenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
     *
     */
    public static UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken unauthenticated(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);
    }

    /**
     * This factory method can be safely used by any code that wishes to create a
     * authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
     *
     */
    public static UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticated(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials, authorities);
    }
}
```

If a developer leverages the Spring Security implementation of the `AuthenticationManager` -- the `ProviderManager` --, and of the `AuthenticationProvider` -- which for the username-password style of authentication is the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` --, they can rest assured that the user's credentials will be erased anyways before the authentication is set into the `SecurityContextHolder`. The `ProviderManager` class invokes the `eraseCredentials()` method, from the `CredentialsContainer` functional interface, to erase the credentials from the authenticated token.

I highly recommend that you use what the Spring Security team has already implemented, as their implementations were already tested and proven to be secure.

If you want to know more about the Spring Security Authentication Architecture, you can take a look into [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication) of the Spring Security reference documentation.